# Angular: transclusion, set color of SVG element

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a `component.html` that transcludes my svg component:

```
<masterflex-sidebar>
    <masterflex-logo sidebar-logo color="white">

    </masterflex-logo>
</masterflex-sidebar>
```

My `logo.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'masterflex-logo',
  templateUrl: './masterflex.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./masterflex.component.scss']
})
export class MasterflexComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() color:string

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My svg component(part of it):

```
<svg 
    version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 237.4 35.9"
    height="35.9"
    width="237.4"
    xml:space="preserve" *ngIf="color">
```

I want to be able to change the color of my svg component to whatever color I want (*set in my first component with color="white"*) and have that color apply to my svg.  Is there a way to pass that color attribute into a scss style?

Comment: What do you mean by "passing the color attribute into a scss style"? You could use property binding to set the color of the SVG element. Would that work for you?

Comment: @ConnorsFan That would work, I was just thinking of how to do it but haven't been able to figure it out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An SVG element has a `stroke` and a `fill` color. You can set each one with the corresponding element or style attribute:

```
<svg [attr.stroke]="color" ... >
<svg [style.stroke]="color" ... >
<svg [attr.fill]="color" ... >
<svg [style.fill]="color" ... >
```

The `color` input property of the component must be set in the parent component:

```
<my-svg-component [color]="myCustomColor" ...>
```

You can try the code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-ucvk3r). Please note that if shape and text elements inside of the SVG element set their own `stroke` or `fill` colors, these will override the color set at the SVG element level.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I needed.  Is there a place where I can read on what that [] thing is in the element?  I'm having a hard time navigating the angular doc

Comment: Yes, you can read about Angular property binding in [this page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) of the documentation. Actually, the whole page about template syntax is a must read.

Comment: is it possible to change fill color when I was using `img` tag wrapped around svg image

Comment: @PardeepJain - According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933495/1009922), it seems to be possible only for inline SVG. I haven't been successful when trying to modifiy the fill color of an SVG element used as an image `src`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, Even I've tried and finally end up using background-mask of HTML element as an SVG image and gave a background color to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

```
<svg 
    version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 237.4 35.9"
    height="35.9"
    width="237.4"
    xml:space="preserve" 
    style="color: {{color}}" *ngIf="color">
```

Or apply it similarly to each style rule you have within your `<svg></svg>` tags. Not sure if it is [`fill`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/fill/) instead of `color` you are after since it is an `svg`. See if it worked or not.

Comment: Didn't work.  The attribute appears as just style on the tag but with no color attribute nor its value.