# select and unselect is not working in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Hi am making a filter by selecting a icon it highlighted the section and after unselect it doesn't highlighted it  but when i select it it works fine but on unselect its icon is disappeared and also it is still selected when i refresh the page, please check this images for reference [when selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dozDL.png) and when [i unselect it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJahn.png) and when i refresh the page [it show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTDZ3.png)

here is my working code

**HTML Code** -

```
<div class="flexcell">
 <a *ngIf="data.showcase==1||helper.checkArticleArray(showcasearticle,data.articleid)"
             href="javascript:void(0);"
            (click)="setShowcase(data.articleid,$event)"><svg
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18"
             viewBox="0 0 18 18">
           <g id="Group_35" data-name="Group 35"
           transform="translate(-556 -363)">
           <rectid="Rectangle_37" data-name="Rectangle 37"
           width="18" height="18" rx="2"
           transform="translate(556 363)" fill="#2262a0" />
          <path id="star" />
     </g>
     </svg></a>
```

Here is my **Node code**

```
showcase(articleid,articlepara){

return this.http.post<any>(this.SERVERURL + this.AppSettings.showcase, {articleid: articleid, articlepara : articlepara});
```

}

and **Here is my .ts file**

```
   `setShowcase(articleid, event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.display = "none";

    this.article.showcase(articleid, this.articlepara)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          //console.log(res);
          this.showcasearticle.push(res.articleid);
          console.log(this.showcasearticle);

        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      )
  }
```

`

Comment: Not sure how are you keeping the value persistent without knowing how your article.showcase works. Add the code block for the function.

The reason it's diapering it's because you are setting display to none, I guessing you suppose to update fill color, not set display to none.

Comment: i added my node code also please check it once

Answer (score 0):

You are setting event.currentTarget.style.display = "none"; which is causing it to disappear. What you need is to replace the fill color. You can refer to this to know more about svg manipulation in angular [Angular: transclusion, set color of SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814394/angular-transclusion-set-color-of-svg-element)